# TYPO3: Modifying TSConfig for 1 page doesn't work for cs_seo

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I am using the extension [cs_seo](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/cs_seo/) v3.1 for [TYPO3 v8](https://get.typo3.org/version/8).7.24

I am following the instructions in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/clickstorm/cs_seo/3.1/en-us/Configuration/Index.html) for disabling the  extension on a specific page by entering the following in the page `tsConfig`

```
 # page TSconfig
 mod.web_layout.tx_csseo.disable = 0
```

However the meta tags still load at the top of the page ?

```
<title>Test Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost/page-title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="Test type" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Test title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Test desc" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost/page-title" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Test Site" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost/fileadmin/templates/facebook.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://localhost/fileadmin/templates/twitter_default.jpg" />
```

Even selecting the "Title only" option the content still appears.

Anyone know any reason why this content would still load, when I view my page tsConfig it comes up as below under the mod/weblayout branch

[image]

There is also the following config for the page :
[image]

I need this page to load without these additional tags ! Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*mod.web_layout.tx_csseo.disable = 0* is a setting to disable evaluations in the backend. This does **not** change any thing in the frontend.

It seems, you have to override/unset some TS-settings one this page. Have a look in https://github.com/clickstorm/cs_seo/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/Meta/openGraph.typoscript an the other TS files of EXT:cs_seo

Comment: Hi, thanks you, As an example ive tried adding the following TypoScript into my 
Page TSConfig
`page.headerData.654 {
  ### title ###
  5 = USER
  5.userFunc = Clickstorm\CsSeo\UserFunc\PageTitle->render
  5.stdWrap.wrap = <title>TEST|</title>
}`
But nothing changes, is there a different parent tag I need to use other than `page.HeaderData.654` ?

Comment: Page TSConfig is added in the page properties. These settings belong to the **backend**.
If you wanna change something for the **frontend**, your TypoScript has to be added as TS Setup via a record of type "TS Template" on your (root)page.